# I Can't Start Activity After Firebase Auth Register

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-authentication

I'm making an ordering app for my lesson. I'm using firebase for authentication. Login Screen is my MainActivity.

On Signup Screen without Signing up I can get back to LoginScreen. But after registration project stops working, can't start other activity. I tried `getApplicationContext()` and `ActivityName.this` to start activity both worked before registration but didn't work after registration. Although the error project registers the user.

This is my LoginScreen (MainActivity):-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn_login;
EditText et_username,et_password;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null)
    {
        intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),OrderScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    btn_login= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    Button btn_signup= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
    et_username= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    et_password= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);

    btn_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), KayitOl.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Login();
        }
    });

}

public void Login()
{
    String email,password;
    email=et_username.getText().toString().trim();
    password=et_password.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"E-mail ve Şifre Giriniz",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),OrderScreen.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}`
```

And this is my RegisterScreen (KayitOl.java)

```
public class KayitOl extends AppCompatActivity{

Button btn_register;
EditText et_email,et_password;
TextView tv_login;
ProgressDialog pd;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kayit_ol);

    firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth .getInstance();

    pd=new ProgressDialog(this);
    btn_register= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
    et_email= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    et_password= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    tv_login= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_login);

    btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Signup();
        }
    });

    tv_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

private void Signup()
{
    String email,password;
    email=et_email.getText().toString().trim();
    password=et_password.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Lütfen Mail ve Şifre Giriniz",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    else
    {
        pd.setMessage("Kayıt Olunuyor");
        pd.show();
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(KayitOl.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(KayitOl.this,"Kayıt Olundu",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    et_email.setText("");
                    et_password.setText("");
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(KayitOl.this,"Kayıt Olunamadı",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".KayitOl">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".OrderScreen"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: after registration, is the app crashing(if so show the logcat) or is it showing this Toast.makeText(KayitOl.this,"Kayıt Olunamadı",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } , `Toast` message

Comment: After registration app is crashing but it's not showing that toast I can't show log because Genymotion's internet didn't register I also tried my phone but it crushes when app opening. Only apk works on phone.

Comment: check if the id of btn_register is correct, also is the `pd` appearing or this toast `"Kayıt Olundu"`?

Comment: Pd appearing. After few seconds it's dissappears and toast "Kayıt olundu" appears. When I comment intent lines inside  if(task.isSuccesfull) I don't get any crush but I can't start MainActivity either

Answer (score 0):

Add onStart method to your login Activity, which according to Firebase docs is:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
   FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
   updateUI(currentUser);
}
```

Comment: I'll try thanks. But is this relative with intent crush

Comment: I can't because genymotions internet didn't signup and my phone only works with apk file

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get you there. What do you your phone only works with apk file?

Comment: I mean I can't use my phone as a emulator and genymotion's internet didn't allow to register